# trying to iterate over JSON structure using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I'm new to jquery and JSON. I have the following JSON structure.

```
{
   "address":{
      "suburb":[
         "HACKHAM WEST",
         "HUNTFIELD HEIGHTS",
         "ONKAPARINGA HILLS",
         "m"
      ],
      "state":"SA"
   }
}
```

So basically the above is the response from this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'getAddress.php',
    data:postCode='+postCode',
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response)
    }
});
```

So, what I'm trying to get is a variable containing state, and an array containing the suburbs.

Comment: Your `data` is wrong in your `$.ajax`.  It should be `data: 'postCode='+postCode,`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check you have valid Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getAddress.php",
    data: {
        postCode : postCode          // data as object is preferrable
    },
    dataType: "json",                // to parse response as JSON automatically
    success: function(response) {
        var state = response.address.state;
        var suburbs = response.address.suburb;
    }
});
```

Comment: I see.. So, I need the dataType to be 'json'? Thanks

Comment: @user933791 If you expect the server to return json, you mightaswell specify json as the datatype. If you return proper headers from the server jQuery *might* detect that it as json, but it is usually better to specify it.

Comment: @user933791 Yep. Otherwise, `getAddress.php` should send the following content type in header: `header("Content-Type: application/json");`.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```
$.ajax({type:'POST', 
    url: 'getAddress.php', 
    dataType: 'json',
    data:'postCode='+postCode, 
    success: function(response) {
        var state = response.address.state;
        var suburbs = response.address.suburb;   
    }
});
```

Added `dataType:'json'` and fixed the `data` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the JSON you get.  `$.ajax` can do this for you.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'getAddress.php',
    data: 'postCode='+postCode, // make sure this line is correct
    dataType: 'json', // this tells jQuery to parse it for you
    success: function(response) {
        var state = response.address.state;
        var suburbs = response.address.suburb;
    }
});
```